# Create mask to select the black area

Tags: c++, opencv, mask

I have a black area around my image and I want to create a mask using OpenCV C++ that selects just this black area so that I can paint it later. How can i do that without affecting the image itself?

I tried to convert the image to grayscale and then using threshold to convert it to binary, but it affects my image since the result contains black pixels from inside the image.

[image]

**Another Question :** if i want to crop the image instead of paint it, how can i do it??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This question is a lot better/clearer than your last one on that topic!

Answer (score 2):

I would solve the problem like this:

1. Inverse-binarize the image with a threshold of 1 (i.e. all pixels with the value 0 are set to 1, all others to 0)
2. use `cv::findContours` to find white segments
3. remove segments that don't touch image borders
4. use `cv::drawContours` to draw the remaining segments to a mask.

There is probably a more efficient solution in terms of runtime efficiency, but you should be able to prototype my solution quite quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, How can i remove segments that don't touch image borders?? sorry, but i am a beginner in this field.

Comment: The contours are sets of points. If a contour touches an image border, then at least one point will lie on the border. The coordinates of the contour points are returned by `findContours` and checking each point against the border is easy: x==0 || y == 0 || x == width-1 || y == height-1 (you might have to add or subtract 1 here, I don't remember how `findContours` handles the image border.)